# Using the File::Copy to copy a file

Tags: perl

I'm trying out a simple program to copy a file. But the program dies with an error.

The code I'm trying is:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w 
use File::Copy
#my $source = "1.txt";
#my $dest = "copy.txt";
copy("1.txt","copy.txt") or die"Copy failed $!\n";
```

And the error message is:

syntax error at 3.pl line 5, near ") or"
Execution of 3.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: *Always* start with `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a semicolon `;`

```
use File::Copy;
```